# How to add headers and body to a python request

Tags: python, get, request

I created a GET request in Python for an API and I would like to add headers and body

```
import urllib2
import os

proxy = 'http://26:Do@proxy:8080'

os.environ['http_proxy'] = proxy
os.environ['https_proxy'] = proxy
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = proxy
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = proxy

contents = urllib2.urlopen("https://xxxx/lista?zile=50 ").read()
```

I tried in Postman and I received a response and I would like to receive the same response in python. How can I add headers and body ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) says `urlopen` returns a file-like object with three extra functions, including `info` which returns headers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `urlopen` function with a `Request` object: 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen

This `Request` object can contain headers and body:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request

Example: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#data

P.S: HTTP GET requests don't have a body. Maybe you meant POST or PUT?

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use the request library which is pretty simple to use. https://realpython.com/python-requests/

example:

```
import requests

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
data_json = {"some_key": "some_value"}

response = requests.post("https://xxxx/lista?zile=50", headers=headers, json=data_json)
```